# How to correctly loop a switch?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner at Java and I want to get into it and I enjoy playing around with it. So I started doing an online course.

So after a few videos I learned a bit about switch statements and wanted to know how to loop them effectively.

```
package v1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Computer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Computer is booting up...");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Mindows '93, please enter a command.");

        String command = input.nextLine();
        boolean computerON = true;

        while (computerON) {

            switch (command) {
            case "!music":
                System.out.println("Playing music!");
                break;
            case "!browse":
                System.out.println("Launching browser...");
                break;
            case "!help":
                System.out.println("Here are the commands that can be used !music, !browse, !shutdown");
                break;
            case "!shutdown":
                System.out.println("Shutting down Mindows, goodbye!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Command not recognised, type !help for a list of commands...");
                break;
            }
            if (command.equals("!shutdown")) {
                computerON = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically what I want is to make a mock text-based OS called Mindows with very limited functionality, but I'm having problems.

When I input `!music`, the program will constantly spam lines of "Playing music!"

When I enter `!shutdown`, however, it terminates which is what I want.

*What I want is* to type !music, !browse, !help and (x) to get the default message without the program spamming lines OR terminating.

I want to be able to type these commands in constantly until the `!shutdown` command is issued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going into an infinite loop because you are accepting input from the user *before the loop*, and the input doesn't change during the execution of the loop. So if you entered "!music", the command doesn't change throughout the loop and the `switch` statement always goes into `case "!music":` in each iteration of the loop, which is why `computerON` is always true and the loop executes and prints "Playing music" infinitely.

The solution to this would be to move the `String command = input.nextLine();` statement inside the while loop, like the above answers say.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Scott Wilks if you are satisfied with either of the answers here please accept that answer which you like the best/which you are most satisfied with to close the question.

Answer (score 4):

You read the command only once, out of your loop.

Try moving the line:

```
String command = input.nextLine();
```

**into** the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Changed your logic here :

```
    boolean computerON = true;
    while (computerON) {
       String command = input.nextLine();

        switch (command) {
        case "!music":
            System.out.println("Playing music!"); break;

        case "!browse":
            System.out.println("Launching browser...");
            break;

        case "!help":
            System.out.println("Here are the commands that can be used !music, !browse, !shutdown");
            break;

        case "!shutdown":
            System.out.println("Shutting down Mindows, goodbye!");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Command not recognised, type !help for a list of commands...");
            break;
        }
        if (command.equals("!shutdown")){
            computerON = false;
        }

    }
```